# Determine the function

Tags: calculus

Let y = f(x) be a differentiable function where x belongs to real number and satisfies . [image]

We have to dtermine the function.

I tried and differentiate two times and substitute the constants

That is  $y' = 1 +$$1/2$$y''+$ $(y-x)(x)$

Has I have done correct . But now how to proceed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$f(x)=x(1+\int_0^1z^2f(z) dz )+x^2\int_0^1zf(z) dz$$.

Hence $f$ has the form

$f(x)=ax+bx^2$